# ImportError: No module named 'bword2vec'

Tags: python, module, importerror

I am working on a python project, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/run_bsg.py", line 3, in <module>
    from interfaces.interface_configurator import InterfaceConfigurator
  File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/interfaces/interface_configurator.py", line 4, in <module>
    from interfaces.i_bsg import IBSG
  File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/interfaces/i_bsg.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models.bsg import BSG
  File "/home/nayantara/PycharmProjects/BSG/models/bsg.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bword2vec import BWord2Vec
ImportError: No module named 'bword2vec'
```

The relevant line in my `bsg.py` is just

```
from bword2vec import BWord2Vec
```

There's also a file called `bword2vec.py` within the same folder:

```
import pickle
import os
import theano
from support import load, write_vectors, kl_spher
from pickle import UnpicklingError
from libraries.tools.ordered_attrs import OrderedAttrs

## theano configuration
theano.optimizer_including = 'cudnn'

class BWord2Vec(OrderedAttrs):
    #Base class for the Bayesian Skip-gram model, it contains methods that can be 
    #used for multiple variants of BSG.
    def __init__(self):
        OrderedAttrs.__init__(self)
        ...
    def initialize_param(self, param_name, param_value):
        ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue before.
Can you check if you have an `__init__.py` in the same folder?
If missing, manually create the same and try again.
Hopefully, it should work. Please let us know how it goes.

Comment: Yes. The `__init__.py` file is already available within the same folder. But, it doesn't have any code within it. Is that alright?

Comment: Yes. That's alright. It should ideally work. I am not sure if it's a good idea but you could always publish bword2vec.py as a python module using setuptools or something and that'd theoretically be available anywhere and you wouldn't get this import error. Let me know if you are interested in this method.

Comment: Since the project is a pre-developed piece of code available in [this repo](https://github.com/ixlan/BSG), it should pretty much work without any major modifications, right? I am just wondering if it's an error on my end or an issue that needs to be reported to the developers. Could you please try running this project on your end. If it recurs, then we wouldn't need to resolve to the long route.

Comment: Sure, let me give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it a lot

Comment: Hi, I ran the code and I didn't encounter the import error. I got some other error (see below) but I think this part of the code is executed because the import was successful.
```TypeError: ('An update must have the same type as the original shared variable (shared_var=<TensorType(float32, matrix)>, shared_var.type=TensorType(float32, matrix), update_val=Elemwise{add,no_inplace}.0, update_val.type=TensorType(float64, matrix)).')```

I created a virtualenv and made the imports using that. I think that made a difference. And just checking, you are using Python2 right?

Comment: Oh yeah. I meant `run_bgs.py`. I'll reset the environment and check it once again. Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: No problem, Have a nice day.